# How to add points to an approximated spline in xfig?

Tags: vector, drawing, anchor-point, xfig

I want to add points to an approximated spline in Xfig (Anyone familiar with Xfig?). However, no matter where I click, I don't seem to be able to do that. I'm able to add points using the "add points" function, to other objects.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xfig, but I added the tag for you.

Comment: Thanks @Cai.  I suppose a flood of xfig questions are unlikely to show up any time soon, but it deserves a tag.